# Is it possible to associate my Stack Overflow account with more than one Google Login?

Tags: support, login, google, security, merge-accounts

The company where I work does monitor everything we do by intercepting all HTTPS using proxy.
I do not trust them and moreover I suspect them to monitor all of our activities.
So I prefer to not use my main Google Account to login to Stack Overflow at work.

It is possible to associate my Stack Overflow account to more than one Google account and being able to login from more than One Google Account?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add an additional Google login with the following steps:

1. If you are currently logged in *to Google* using the Google account that's already associated with your Stack Overflow account, you will need to log out *from Google* via *e.g.* https://www.google.com/.
2. Go to [Your profile -> Settings -> Your Logins (under access)](/users/mylogins/current).
3. Click the "Add more logins..." button: 
   [image]
4. Click "Add login with Google" 
   **Note!** if you are still logged into Google with an associated account clicking this will redirect you to your Stack Overflow account, go back to step 1 and log out from your Google account to proceed 
   [image]
5. Follow the prompts to complete your Google login.
6. You may also receive an email asking you to verify your new login, you will need to complete these steps as well.
7. Your credential should now be added and appear under [Your Logins](/users/mylogins/current)

---

This answer was created following the instructions and guidance provided in [an answer to "Can one log in using multiple Google accounts with Stack Overflow?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110839/1099857) on Meta Stack Exchange.